# Обработка js скрипта без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть скрипт, который заменяет один див на другой в зависимости от введенного значения в поле _calculated_price_ :

```
var price = document.getElementById('calculated_price').innerHTML;
var mainBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('home-main-block_price')[0];
if (price == 1) {
    var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
    modal.classList += ' visible';
    mainBlock.classList += ' hidden';}
```

при загрузке страницы, поле _calculated_price_ пустое. Оно формируется после загрузки страницы, путем подсчета стоимости.
Как сделать так, чтоб скрипт срабатывал при каждом изменении значения _calculated_price_ и если значение поля становится 1, то вызывал модальное окно:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Позвоните нам!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Это див вывода подсчетов из формы:

```
<div class="home-main-block_price">
    <p>цена</p>
    <span>
        <p id="calculated_price" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 34px;></p>
    </span>
        <p>с НДС</p>
    <button type="button">Заказать</button>
</div>
```

Это скрипт, который берет расчеты из контроллера и записывает в айдишник calculated_price:

```
<script>
        function calc(){
            $('#calculated_price').load('/sum/?'+$('#form').serialize());
        }
    </script>
```

Если вручную ввести значение в поле _calculated_price_ то при загрузке страницы, скрипт срабатывает и появляется модальное окно. В AJAX'е не силен. Всем спасибо.

Comment: Добавьте минимальный рабочий пример как работает код сейчас.

Comment: @MrFylypenko Вот ссылка где значение calculated_price равно, например 10 (https://jsfiddle.net/hsuut13L/), а вот ссылка, где значение равно 1 (https://jsfiddle.net/hsuut13L/1/). Если цена сформировалась и равна 1, то скрипт срабатывает и выдает модальное. Как реализовать, чтоб при каждом изменении цены, этот скрипт "смотрел" на изменения без перезагрузки страницы?

Comment: при изменении цены пересчитываете размеры о которых вы говорите, и по условию далее открываете окно или нет. Какая проблема?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев дело в том, что этот скрипт работает при перезагрузке страницы. А значение цены формируется динамически. Когда вводишь вес 100кг записывается одна цена, тут же стираешь и вводишь другой вес - цена опять меняется. Это все без перезагрузки страницы. Как можно навесить эту функцию на обработчик аякса. Помогите.

Answer (score 0):

Изменил Ваш пример, добавил в функцию `calc` колбек, который выполнится после подгрузки страницы.

```js
function calc() {
  $('#calculated_price').load('/sum/?' + $('#form').serialize(), function() {
    var price = document.getElementById('calculated_price').value;
    var mainBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('home-main-block_price')[0];
    if (price == 1) {
      var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
      modal.classList += ' visible';
      mainBlock.classList += ' hidden';
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.modal-dialog {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-main-block_price">
  <p>цена</p>
  <span>
        <p id="calculated_price" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 34px;"></p>
    </span>
  <p>с НДС</p>
  <button type="button">Заказать</button>
</div>

<div class="modal-dialog" id="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Позвоните нам!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: так суть функции пропала - замена дивов. (https://jsfiddle.net/988cajkw/) calculated_price должен быть в первом диве. Я так понимаю тут должен быть асинхронный запрос к полю calculated_price АЯКСОМ.

Comment: как можно в данном примере применить объект XMLHttpRequest к изменению значений в поле `<p id="calculated_price"></p>`??

Comment: Как оно изменяется сейчас, по какому событию?

Comment: цена в `<p id="calculated_price"></p>` генерируется в контроллере, после ввода веса, и возвращается в значение блока _calculated_price_ также без перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: Вы говорите что это поле изменяется без перезагрузки страницы, каким образом оно меняется неизвестно и воспроизводимого примера нет. Дополните вопрос этой информацией. Кстати, какой контроллер (ангулар)?

Comment: добавил в пример обработчик стоимости, который записывает цену в `<p id="calculated_price"></p>`. Контроллер mvc

Comment: функция `load` позволяет выполнить код  после загрузки данных `$('#calculated_price').load('url', function(){  //некий код });` внутри этой функции и сделайте проверку поля `_calculated_price_`

Comment: Обновил ответ, просто используйте функцию `calc`, она сама подменит значение после подгрузки страницы

Comment: дело в том, что `onclick="calc()"` не должно навешиватся на кнопку. Это должно происходить автоматически, когда вдруг цена станет значением 1.

Comment: `calc` должна вызываться как и раньше, не по моей кнопке

Comment: classList умеет в конкатенацию?

Comment: @vp_arth оказывается да, нажмите на кнопку в  [примере](http://plnkr.co/edit/SzbvPyYMR6wOXufpnyLp?p=preview)

Comment: @MrFylypenko Спасибо за пример. Все работает. А подскажите пожалуйста еще такое. Из Вашего примера (http://plnkr.co/edit/SzbvPyYMR6wOXufpnyLp?p=preview). Как можно дополнить условие, что если цена больше или равно 100, то вернуть первый див с ценой. Спасибо.

Comment: @Viktor Сделал вот такую [переключалку](http://plnkr.co/edit/SzbvPyYMR6wOXufpnyLp?p=preview) (без классов , меняю css свойства), в ней добавил метод, который возвращает предыдущий див, Вам нужно смотреть [сюда](http://javascript.ru/ui/show-hide-toggle) и по этой логике добавляйте условия.